# How to write awk script inside my script?

Tags: bash, shell, awk

I wrote one script to populate column from another column. So for that below is my script file-
For that i copied column data to another file-

script.sh-

```
  echo "number of parameters is $#"

  if [ $# != 1 ]; then
  USAGE="USAGE: $0 cassPassword"
  echo ${USAGE}
  exit 1
  fi

  Password=$1


  echo "copy home.admin (my_references, id, eff_date) to 'myStatement.cql';" > copyInputs.cql
  cqlsh -u dgadmin -p ${cassPassword} -f copyInputs.cql

  cp myStatement.cql updatestmt.cql
```

After that i have created a seperate awk script for some string manipulation
my_refs.awk

```
     #!awk
      BEGIN { FS = "," }  # split fields on comma
       {

        doing some manipulation

sub(/,$/, "", crefs)  # remove trailing comma
crefs=crefs"}"
print "update table set cross_refs ="crefs" where id='"$(NF-1)"' and effective_date ='"$(NF)"'"
   }
```

Run through awk-f my_refs.awk updatestmt.cql > updateStatement.cql 
After getting value in updateStatement.cql again going back to my sh script and doing some modification.

```
sed -i "s/$/';/" updateStatement.cql
```

Can't i write awk script inside my shell script file??So that i can avoid two step process

Comment: This can most likely be done without writing the data to a file at all. Do you need all these *.cql files lying around?

Comment: Sir i was doing some update operation against cassandra db using sh

Comment: Your script creates "copyInput.sql", "myStatement.cql", "updatestmt.cql" and "updateStatement.cql" -- do you need the copyInput file or the myStatement file or the updatestmt file after the script is finished?

Comment: I got it.. what you are pointing to. I agree i dont need all .*cql file

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you can write:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [[ $# -eq 0 ]]; then
    echo "usage: $0 cassPassword" >&2
    exit 1
fi

echo "copy home.admin (my_references, id, eff_date);" |
cqlsh -u dgadmin -p "$1" |
awk '
    BEGIN {
        FS = ","
        update_fmt = "update table set cross_refs=%s where id='\''%s'\'' and effective_date='\''%s'\'';"
    }
    {
        # ... some manipulation: I assume you create "crefs" variable here
        sub(/,$/, "}", crefs)
        printf(update_fmt, crefs, $(NF-1), $NF);
    }
' > updateStatement.cql
```

bash does not allow to you embed a single quote in a single quoted string. The entire awk script is the single quoted string, and I want to put single quotes in the "update_fmt" string. That's why you see the strange looking `'\''`

The `echo`, `cqlsh` and `awk` commands are all connected with pipes, so you don't need any temporary files. I'm assuming cqlsh is OK with reading commands from stdin and writing to stdout.

Answer (score 0):

Yes - you can paste your awk command right into your shell script:

```
# beginning part omitted...
cp myStatement.cql updatestmt-temporary.cql
awk -f my_refs.awk updatestmt-temporary.cql > updateStatement.cql
sed -i "s/$/';/" updateStatement.cql
rm updatestmt-temporary.cql
```

Comment: Sir , how this part will work? Since i pasted awk code in my script

awk-f my_refs.awk updatestmt-temporary.cql > updateStatement.cql 

my_refs.awk is the name of my awk file? but here incase what shall i give?

Comment: @okla yes, `my_refs.awk` should be the name of the file holding your awk program.  This command works in `script.sh` the same as when you type it at the command line.